# Buffer overflow - strange arrangement on stack

Tags: c

I tried to perform a little buffer overflow attack on the following code. When i opened up the programm in gdb there appeared a wrong order on the stack and I don't know why.

```
(gdb) list
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
8       int auth_flag=0;
9       char pwd_buffer[16];
10      strcpy(pwd_buffer,pPwd);
11      if(strcmp(pwd_buffer,"pass")==0)auth_flag=1;
12      return auth_flag;
13  }
14  
15  
16  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
17  {
(gdb) 
18      if(argc<2){
19          printf("\nUsage <%s password>\n\n",argv[0]);
20          exit(0);
21      }
22      if(authenticate(argv[1])){
23          printf("-----------------------------------\n");
24          printf("         ACCESS GRANTED\n");
25          printf("-----------------------------------\n");
26      }
27      else {
(gdb) 
28          printf("-----------------------------------\n");
29          printf("         ACCESS DENIED\n");
30          printf("-----------------------------------\n");
31      }
32      return 0;
33  }
(gdb) break 10
Haltepunkt 1 at 0x804855d: file main.c, line 10.
(gdb) run AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Starting program: /home/phydor/C/Overflow/a.out AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Breakpoint 1, authenticate (pPwd=0xbffff34d 'A' <repeats 40 times>) at main.c:10
10      strcpy(pwd_buffer,pPwd);
(gdb) x/s pwd_buffer 
0xbffff07c: 'A' <repeats 40 times>
(gdb) x/d &auth_flag 
0xbffff078: 0
(gdb)
```

I don't understand why *pwd_buffer* is filled with the parameter before executing the *strcpy()* command and why the buffer is positioned at a higher address than *auth_flag* because the stack grows in the direction of lower addresses.

Comment: You should have a look at the assembly to understand what is happening.

Comment: well gdb is telling you that the source code you show doesnt match the binary you are running "warning: Source file is more recent than executable."

Comment: Try to compile with all optimisations disabled (-O0 option). Also you can try to initialize auth_flag after all declarations to let the compiler working on simple pieces of code step by step.